# Problems Importing My Files

Tags: java, eclipse

I've recently gotten a new laptop and I am having problems importing my projects. I used Airdrop to import my projects into my new Eclipse folder. When I imported it shows errors. Any way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: There's probably one or two things to correct and it will clear up. Take the first error and see if you can find out what it's unhappy with. You will have to give more details about the error messages though. It could be missing libraries, mismatching java versions, hardcoded paths in your build path that are different on your new computer, etc.

Comment: Please add the full error details to your question, It's hard to see from the image what the problem is.

Comment: Cristik, I gave a picture and information. Also, I said that it was solved. No need to vote the thread as negitive.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Just make a new project and drag imported files from old computer to the new project.